# What benefits does JSON dot-notation give over hierarchical structure?

Tags: java, json

We are working on a Java REST service which accepts JSON input but the consumers of this service want to send the json in dot-notation format instead of hierarchical structure.

So for example they prefer following input -

```
{
  “person.address.city”: “San Francisco”
}
```

over:

```
{
  “person”:{
            “address”:{
                       “city”: “San Francisco”
                      }
           }
}
```

Does the former notation have any benefits over the latter?

I could find below article which talks about this way of data representation:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/simple-dot-notation-access-to-json-data.html#GUID-7249417B-A337-4854-8040-192D5CEFD576

Edit: From Java perspective, the hierarchical structure can be deserialized into typed classes. On the other hand, the dot-notation might have to be parsed as strings to get values.

Answer (score 2):

This is just another OVER format (arrangement). Simplifies reading. It has nothing to do with the JSON format itself.

It could also be:

```
{
  “person/address/city”: “San Francisco”
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of the *dot notation* is that it flattens out the hierarchical structure, making it easier to store / manipulate the data in non hierarchical systems.

Using dot notation, you can transform a complex tree structure to a simple key value pairs structure. You can then store it to a simple Java `HashMap` or even in a [Redis Hash](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro).

This is how traditional [key-value stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database) can expand their use cases to include more complex storage requirements.